# Define a relative path folder inside a function that run code on both cmd and IDE

Tags: python, cmd, path, ide

## What I Have

I have a code that run on cmd but didn't work well on my IDE (pycharm) because of file path definition. My project folder structure is:

```
-broker
    -data
        -sample.pdf
    -output
    -report
    -script
        -functions.py
    -venv
```

The function below is on functions.py file and need to read the sample.pdf file inside data folder.

## What I've Already Tried

Create two solution to run in each interpreter. Both work properly.

```
# run well on IDE
pdf_path = pl.Path.cwd() / 'data' / file_name

# run well on cmd
pdf_path = pl.Path(r'../data') / file_name
```

This is the entire code.

```
def extract_pdf(file_name):
    """
    A function to extract data from stock market broker notes

    """

    # load modules
    import PyPDF2 as p2
    import pathlib as pl

    # assign file path to a variable
    pdf_path = pl.Path(r'../data') / file_name

    # read pdf file
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_fread = p2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

        # extract all pages from pdf file
        n = 0
        while n < pdf_fread.getNumPages():
            page = pdf_fread.getPage(n)
            print(page.extractText())
            n = n + 1
```

## Expected and Actual Results

This code run well on cmd since I have to get inside script folder and run file or import module.

**I apreciate any help to create just one path that work in both cmd and IDE enviroment.**

Comment: This is more of an IDE configuration issue than a programming on per se.  You can go to Run->Edit configurations... and set the working directory to be script\.  Then your '../data' option should work.

Comment: Thanks. That's clear for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - the script you run from cmd "sits" in the `script` folder. The function, which you run when in PyTorch, let's call it `main` - "sits" directly in the `broker` directory.

So, you can either move your script up in the folders tree or specify a different working directory for the `main` function, so when it is run inside the IDE it has the same "home directory" as would the script when run from cmd.

You can do this in PyCharm by editinig the working directory in the "Run/Debug Configurations".
Look at the last option in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tim. But if I change my work directory (IDE) my path on code have to be one (see example posted) based on my work directory. So if I run that same code from cmd will get a `error` because of that `pdf_path` informed. How to write a realtive path that works on both situation?

Comment: Sorry, Tim. With Fiddle's explanation all be clear. You are rigth. Thanks.

Comment: @ElsiorMoreiraAlvesJunior, I've just edited my answer, I hope I got you right.